# Issue with using except invalid syntax

Tags: python, list, exception, syntax-error, nameerror

I'm trying to write a code. Code needs to append elem to a list "a" if the name or syntax error doesn't occur. But the function doesn't even work, because this error stops function at the beginning.

```
def printing(list):
    a = []
    b = []
    try:
        for elem in list:
            a.append(elem)
    except (SyntaxError,NameError):
        for elem in list:
            b.append(elem)
    return a,b

print(printing(1,2,1o,o))
```

Desire output `a = [1,2] b = [1o,o]`

Comment: Where are the 1o and o variables defined?

Comment: you get error before it starts `printing` so using `try/except` inside function can't help. You would have to put `printing(1,2,1o,o)` inside `try/except` to catch error. But this can't help you because you can't get wrog names. It checks variables before it put them to `printing(...)` and you can't get them.

Comment: You're passing four variables to the function, and it only accepts one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not issues but Python works in different way then you expect.

First it gets code as text, next it parses it, and finally it runs it.

And `SyntaxError` is raised when it parses code - so you can't catch it inside code when it runs it.

There is example with `exec()` which has to parse text with code.

It shows message from external `try/except`

```
text = '''def printing(list):
    a = []
    b = []
    
    try:
        for elem in list:
            a.append(elem)
    except (SyntaxError,NameError):
        for elem in list:
            b.append(elem)
            
    return a,b
    
# ---    

print(printing([1, 2, 1o, o]))
'''

try:    
    exec(text)
except SyntaxError as ex:
    print('I catched exception:', ex.msg)
    print('I catched exception:', text.splitlines()[(ex.lineno-1)])
    print('I catched exception:', " "*(ex.offset-1) + "^")
```

If you try to use code `1o` directly in `try/except` then it can't catch it - because it is too late for this.

```
def printing(list):
    a = []
    b = []
    
    try:
        for elem in list:
            a.append(elem)
    except (SyntaxError,NameError):
        for elem in list:
            b.append(elem)
            
    return a,b
    
# ---    

try:    
    print(printing([1, 2, 1o, o]))
except SyntaxError as ex:
    print('I catched exception:', ex.msg)
    print('I catched exception:', text.splitlines()[(ex.lineno-1)])
    print('I catched exception:', " "*(ex.offset-1) + "^")
```

---

Similar problem is with `NameError` (I used `lo` instead of `1o` to skip `Syntax Error` and get `NameError`). It raises this error when you try to create list `[1, 2, lo, o]` , not when you try to get it inside function.

Code `[1, 2, lo, o]` tries to find variable `lo` to get value from this variable and put it in list. And at this moment it has problem with `NameError`.

Function gets only list with values, not with names of variables.

```
def printing(list):
    a = []
    b = []
    
    try:
        for elem in list:
            a.append(elem)
    except (SyntaxError,NameError):
        for elem in list:
            b.append(elem)
            
    return a,b
    
# ---    

try:    
    print(printing([1, 2, lo, o]))
except NameError as ex:
    print('I catched exception:', ex)
```